# How can i get the sum of the numbers produced by a loop

Tags: c

```
do
    {
        sum = ((card % x) / y) * 2;
        if (sum >= 10)
        {
            sum = sum % 10 + (sum % 100) / 10;
        }

        printf("%ld\n", sum);
        
        x *= 100;
        y *= 100;

    }
    while (x <= 10000000000000000);// calculates every other digit multiplied by 2
```

output:

```
2
0
0
0
0
3
0
8
```

I need to get the sum which is 13 in this case.
I'm a beginner and been stuck on this for a while, a little help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: please post a [mre]

Comment: @Barmar has fixed it for u

Answer (score 1):

Add another variable that accumulates the total.

```
long int total = 0;
do
    {
        sum = ((card % x) / y) * 2;
        if (sum >= 10)
        {
            sum = sum % 10 + (sum % 100) / 10;
        }

        printf("%ld\n", sum);
        total += sum;
        
        x *= 100;
        y *= 100;

    }
    while (x <= 10000000000000000);// calculates every other digit multiplied by 2
printf("Total = %ld\n", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of going at this, but I suggest that you look into recursive functions--since you mentioned you are a beginner. After years of coding in C, I find myself implementing recursive functions most naturally on these types of tasks.

I acknowledge that you mentioned using while loop. You can still use recursion to do the exact same thing you are trying to achieve with the loop by using if statement. Also, I would pass in the variables you use in the recursive function parameter.

There are thousands of tutorials and examples of recursion online. I highly recommend you get familiar with them. Cheers!